# Efficient method to store z3 symbolic expression into the key of a dictionary

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using `Z3Py` to develop some tools, and in my code, I maintain multiple `dictionaries` to keep track of some information.

Note that sometimes I need to use the `z3` expression as the key of certain dictionary, and since `z3` expression is not hashable (am I right?), what I am doing right now is:

1. translate `z3` expression into string using the `Python str` function.
2. store the `string` representation as the key of the dictionary.

However, some profiling and observation shows that the translation from `z3` expression to `string` takes quite a lot of time, and it has become a bottleneck of my code.

So here is my question, what is the most efficient way to use a `z3` expression as a key in a dictionary? Or is there any workaround solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions should be hashable. Expressions override the **hash** and the **eq** methods. 
The visitor example, https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/python/visitor.py, uses a dictionary.

As a side-note, I doubt this is relevant in common cases: Another property you can rely on is that expressions have unique integer identifiers. The method "get_id()" returns the identifier. This offers another way to index into expressions. The identifiers for expressions are numbers starting from 0. The maximal identifier is never more than the number of expressions created. If expressions are garbage collected, then identifiers are recycled. So of course make sure to pin expressions in the heap if you use this feature.

Comment: I am actually extending that `visitor` example for my purpose! Let me see where is the issue..

Comment: OK, I eventually figured it out that it is because my `z3Py` is out dated. By updating with the newest version on github, it becomes hashable.